# Error in search from multi-tables by php and my sql

Tags: php, mysql, union

Now I'm trying to search in multi table  but now my problem how to know which table you got the data ??

```
$query="(SELECT name  FROM news WHERE name like '%$SER%' ) 
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT name  FROM media WHERE name like '%$SER%') ";
$res=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
echo $row[prog]."<br>";
}
mysql_num_rows($res);
```

How to know the result got from which table !!!

Comment: It doesn't look like you're doing any [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) here and you have some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and provides a simple, reliable way of adding data to queries. `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) outlines the recommended best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an extra column

```
select 1 as FromTable
UNION
select 2 as FromTable;
```

Anything from the second select will have `2` as `$row["FromTable"]`

You also NEED to read about SQL injections, and use the mysqli APIs instead ideally (`?` saves both parsing time, escaping time and the need to escape!)